# NoMethodError undefined method `alq' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror

Im prety new on rails, and this is my first solo app. I use the Prawn-rails to generate PDFs.

Right now, im trying add lines depending on the number of lines defined at l_answer

Im getting this error: ***NoMethodError in Exams#show - undefined method `alq' for 1:Fixnum***

My Prawn code:

```
@exam.line_questions.each do |q| 

pdf.text "#{q.question.question}"
pdf.move_down(5)
pdf.text "#{q.question.l_answer.alq}"
pdf.move_down(30)

end
```

Im getting the error at: pdf.text "#{q.question.l_answer.alq}"

This is my model class for question:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

DISCIPLINA_TYPE = ["Portugues", "Matematica", "Estudo do Meio"]
ANO_TYPE = ["1º Ano", "2º Ano", "3º Ano", "4º Ano"]

has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum

has_many :line_questions

validates :title , presence:true , uniqueness: true
validates :question, presence:true
validates :disciplina, inclusion: DISCIPLINA_TYPE
validates :ano, inclusion: ANO_TYPE
def alq
  linhas = question.l_answer
  for i in linhas do
    until i <= linhas
      if i = 1 
        "R:________________________________________"
        i +=1
      else
        "__________________________________________"
        i += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

Well maybe im not explaining my self very well...

l_answer is an argument of the class Question.

So i defined the a new Question.

So that question will have 4 lines to answer so l_answer = 4

I change my code a litle to this:

```
def alq(l_answer)
  l = l_answer
  for i in l do
    until i = 0
      if i = 1 
        "R:________________________________________"
        i -=1
      else
        "__________________________________________"
        i -= 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the Prawn pdf file to this:

```
@exam.line_questions.each do |q| 
pdf.text "#{q.question.question}"
pdf.move_down(5)
pdf.text "#{q.question.alq(q.question.l_answer)}"
pdf.move_down(30)

end
```

But now i get this: `` undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum! ``

Is this closer?

@VitalyKushner
As a side note, alq and l_answer are not that good names for methods. You are not saving trees by using less symbols, you are making it harder to read ;) - haahahah thats what being a noob means :). Thanks for the input

Comment: I believe it should be `pdf.text "#{q.question.alq}"` not `pdf.text "#{q.question.l_answer.alq}"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @UriAgassi! I tried that and now i get this error: `undefined method 'l_answer' for nil:NilClass` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in here.

- for...in only works with collections, and l_answer is not.

In fact, IIRC, for loops are transformed by the language to `each` method call, this way:

```
for item in collection do
 # work with item
end
```

gets transformed into

```
collection.each do |item|
 # work with item
end
```

hence your last error message since `each` method is defined on Array and not on Fixnum

- Your first example uses for and until, which are the same things (or quite), this is going to crash.

Try experimenting with `puts` to see what really happens

```
def alq(l_answer)
  l = l_answer
  for i in l do
    puts "#{i} in for loop"
    until i = 0
      puts "#{i} in until loop"
      if i = 1 
        "R:________________________________________"
        i -=1
      else
        "__________________________________________"
        i -= 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There are probably others, which seems normal as I understand you're a beginner, but i'm not here to point at mistakes

For loops are very seldom used in ruby, there are looping methods which use is much more  idiomatic(aka the ruby way). [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Integer.html#method-i-times), [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-each) are two of those. Please also have a look at [Enumerable Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html) which define several other ways to loop through a collection and act on individual items.

From what I understand, this is what you want

```
def alq(l_answer)
  response = []
  l_answer.times do |index|
      if index = 0
        response += "R:________________________________________"
      else
        response += "__________________________________________"
      end
    end
    response.join('\n')
  end
end
```

or even better (I think):

```
def alq(l_answer)

  (0...l_answer).map do |index|
      (index == 0 ? "R:" : '__') + "______________________________________"
  end.join('\n')
end
```

- `(0...l_answer)`is an exclusive `range`, you can see it as [0, 1, 2, ..., l_answer-1]
- `map` is method from [Enumerable module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like `q.question.l_answer` is an integer, and not a `Question`, and of course it doesn't have the `alq` method defined.

As a side note, `alq` and `l_answer` are not that good names for methods. You are not saving trees by using less symbols, you are making it harder to read ;)